# Metamask Token Balance

Tags: erc-20, metamask

When Metamask gets the balance of an erc20 token, does it call the `balanceOf(...)` function on the token contract?

**Context**:
I am trying to implement a token with lockable functionality.
With this token, there is a `balanceOf(...)` function which returns the amount of tokens that are not locked.
There is also a function called `totalBalanceOf(...)` which returns the amount of tokens that are locked and not locked.
It would be helpful to know which amount would be shown in Metamask.

Thank you in advance